# Photonicinduction - Less Turn Equals "Same Amps" but "Less Voltage"

Tags: voltage, transformer, amperage

I was recently watching a video by the youtuber ‘*Photonicinduction*’ and I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ut5DXxK1dvk).
When the video was at 1:50, I noticed that there were 4 Turns on the primary and secondary so its a 1:1 Transformer.

The cable he is using is **400mm** power cable rated at **400A**. He stated that if he got **250A** on the primary, he could get **20kA** on the secondary.
As he is based in the UK, the mains voltage is **240V**. By knowing this, I ran the following calculations:

$$
P=IV
$$
$$
P=(250)(240)=60kW
$$
$$
V=P/I
$$
$$
V=(60kW)/(20kA)=3V
$$

This shows that the voltage going through the secondary is **3V** which explains why he does not get electrocuted. But at 4:33, he reduces the turns to **2 turns** on both sides. He then claims, “*Same amount of amps but, the voltage will be less*.”

I tried to search for an equation to see how this is even possible but, I am not sure what equation he used or even if he used an equation at all.

I was wondering if anyone can show me the mathematical relationship of the number of Turns of the transformer and the voltage.

Comment: It's probably a spoof video like the other ones.

Comment: @Andyaka elaborate

Comment: Nothing to elaborate. Photonic-induction is a made up name and not, as far as I can tell, worthy of discussion on this site.

Comment: it isn't 4 turns on the primary and 4 turns on the secondary, what you are seeing is ONLY the secondary, the primary feed is via the the blue flex and you cannot see the turns

Comment: A lot of what he does is intuition and experience, finger in the air checks. No design calcs etc as he is after having fun.   there is no man behind the curtains going on so when he melts a spanner he has

Comment: He's basically built an arc welder - mains voltage and low current in, low voltage and high current out.

Comment: It's a video which is made to entertain. Unfortunately someone can imagine there's something else which earns to be tried. The low voltage high current effect which melts a thin wire is plausible but also some unrelated clips are inserted. The 4 turns primary and 4 turns secondary at 1:50 is purely your own interpretation. I saw a 8 turns secondary, the primary probably has hundreds times more. I'm afraid that if someone kills people or burns a house when trying to follow the shown examples he cannot get any compensation from the makers of the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the limiting factor is the *wire resistance* - which wouldn't be surprising in Photonicinduction's high-current experiments - then less turns means there is less wire, therefore less resistance, therefore less voltage for the same amount of current.

> I was wondering if anyone can show me the mathematical relationship of the number of Turns of the transformer and the voltage.

The mathematical relationship between number of turns and voltage is quite well-known:

$$\frac{V_1}{N_1} = \frac{V_2}{N_2}$$

that is, the voltage per turn is the same on both sides of the transformer. And the current scales inversely to the voltage:

$${I_1}{N_1} = {I_2}{N_2}$$

---

When considering the wire resistance (not just an ideal transformer), both current and voltage will change when a load is added. When connecting a load \$R_L\$ and a series wire resistance of \$R_W\$ (\$R_{turn}\$ per turn),

$${I_2}
= \frac{V_2}{R_L + R_W}
= \frac{V_{turn}N_2}{R_L + N_2R_{turn}}
= \frac{V_{turn}}{\frac{R_L}{N_2} + R_{turn}}$$

If I haven't made a mistake in my math, *if \$R_L\$ is very low compared to \$R_{turn}\$*, the equation is dominated by \$R_{turn}\$ which does not scale with the number of turns. Whether this is actually true in Photonicinduction's experiments, I'm not sure. Perhaps not, because the \$R_L\$ is the part that gets hot, but then again, the transformer winding has a lot more volume and surface area to dissipate heat compared to the load.

---

> I am not sure what equation he used or even if he used an equation at all.

It is not clear whether he did. He's shown plenty of similar experiments. Of course both the current and voltage will drop when a load is added, but he may have seen that the current remains *about* the same in this kind of scenario and developed it as a rule of thumb.

Or perhaps he meant "same amount of *short-circuit* amps, but the *open-circuit* voltage will be less." It is clear he is able to calculate things *when needed*, but I wouldn't expect to see any of that on his YouTube channel.

Comment: This makes sense but is there anyway to prove that less turns is less resistance?

Comment: @Neamus the turns are all in series, aren't they?